# QuickVoice recordings on iPad

Tags: ipad, icloud, recording

I have a lot of QuickVoice recordings made and stored on my iPad (first generation)

I am attempting to backup to iCloud for the first time.  If this is successful, can I then delete the recordings from my iPad to create some much needed space?

If so, how do I retrieve any specific recordings from iCloud for later use?

Answer (score 1):

You can sync your QuickVoice recordings with a PC or Mac using their software. Have a look at the [QuickVoice website](http://www.nfinityinc.com/quickvoice/index.html) for information on the download and price, although it seems that you get a desktop version with the iOS version, which I didn't get so not sure where to get it.

This app does not use iCloud to sync, it uses its own cloud storage system.